# Can We Use Stored Procedure In Spring Batch ItemProcessor?

Tags: stored-procedures, spring-batch

I did some searching but couldn't find any sample/example.

I've a requirement where some informations from one table (input) are read, processed to a itemprocessor( business logic) that needs to call multiple stored procedures. So one or more objects will result and needs to be inserted into another table (output).

Any ideas? TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the official [Spring Batch Docs: ItemProcessors](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/reference/html-single/index.html#itemProcessor)

> what if you want to insert business logic before writing? One option
>   for writing is to use the composite pattern: create an ItemWriter that
>   contains another ItemWriter

same passage

> However, if you only want to 'transform' the item passed in for
>   writing before it is actually written, there isn't much need to call
>   write yourself: you just want to modify the item. For this scenario,
>   Spring Batch provides the ItemProcessor interface

imho it is no problem to use an ItemProcessor not only for simple "transforming" but for enriching, persisting and so on

for your specific usecase the mentioned *(ItemWriter)composite pattern* could be sufficient

Comment: thank for your response ,but my question is :is it possible to call a stored procedure inside itemprocessor,because my business logic needs some informations in system (A) returned by stored procedure that is specific foreach elements loaded in system(B) by the itemreader

Comment: an ItemProcessor is just a Spring Bean, which can use other Spring Beans, so you could create some DAO beans for your stored procedure calls

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the provided Spring Batch `JdbcBatchItemWriter` can execute only `update`-statements. You need to write you implementation of `ItemWriter` interface with use of [`SimpleJdbcCall`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-simple-jdbc-call-1) or `GenericStoredProcedure` helper classes (see [`StoredProcedure#execute()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-jdbc/3.0.6.RELEASE/org/springframework/jdbc/object/StoredProcedure.java#114) method).